# Display input text in Bootstrap radio-inline list

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some radio-buttons in a Bootstrap 3.3.5 setup. If a certain radio-button is checked an addional input field may be filled. I thus want to place it near that radio button. What is a good way to do that? Whether I place it in the `label` or the `li` - it's always displayed with a break before and breaks the inline display of the radios.

```
        <ul class="list-inline">

            <li>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="rdoInp" id="rdoInp1" value="1"> Radio 1
                </label>
            </li><li>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="rdoInp" id="rdoInp6" value="6"> Radio 6
                </label>
            </li><li>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="rdoInp" id="rdoInp7" value="7"> Radio 7
                    <input type="text" name="txt1" class="form-control col-xs-1">
                </label>
            </li><li>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="rdoInp" id="rdoInp8" value="8"> Radio 8
                </label>
            </li>

        </ul>
```

Unlike answered in Question [add text input to inline radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134255/add-text-input-to-inline-radio-buttons) am I in a `.form-horizontal` formular.

Fiddle: http://www.bootply.com/F57p30Eyo2

Comment: are you looking for something like this (see only radio 7)? http://www.bootply.com/oNp11RQBru (we can make it much better later)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with how you've set up the grid system on your containers rather than the list. You have "col-sm-4" on the containing div. If you change it to "col-sm-12" it displays the text input field inline.

The element simply doesn't fit inline with all the others as part of such a narrow column. For example, applying "width: 50px" to the text field also places it inline.

Comment: I set up `col-sm-4` in this sample as I am in a `modal` in real life.

Comment: I understand, I was just trying to illustrate that as far as I can tell the element is being displayed inline and that there is a break simply because the content doesn't fit in the width of the container.